# URLSession not sending codable struct as request body

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

i am trying to send a POST API call with URLSession, but it is not sending requset body.

my sturct is a Codable sturct, and APi works in Postman

here is my code

```
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: EndPoint.BASE_URL + "SignUp")!)

        urlRequest.httpMethod = "post"
        do {
            let requestBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
            urlRequest.httpBody = requestBody
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
            
        } catch let error {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, httpUrlResponse, error) in
            if(data != nil && data?.count != 0)
            {
                guard let data = data else {return }
                do
                {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(SignUpResponse.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(response))
                    
                }
                catch let decodingError {
                    debugPrint(decodingError.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
```

can you please look, where i am missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

since your request structure inherits from the codable type alias, I think all you have to do is replace the code

`let requestBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)`

with

`let requestBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(YOUR_REQUEST_STRUCTURE)`

apart from that all looks good and also as a sanity check add a debugger to the `URLRequest` and validate if the `URLRequest` is generating the correct SignUp URL that matches the one you have in the postman.

Also its a wise idea to not to use Codable for your request models and just implement the `Encodable protocol` unless you need to.